# How do you (not using keigo) thank someone for giving you permission to do something?

Tags: syntax, keigo, causation

For example, if someone allows me to use their computer, I may say:

> パソコンを使わせていただいてありがとうございます。

(if that is incorrect, let me know!).

But in normal speech, how would you say it in everyday situations?

Answer (score 4):

Formal:

> パソコン**を**使わせて**いただいて**ありがとう**ございます**。

Casual:

> パソコン使わせてくれてありがとう。

Answer (score 1):

Other examples:

> パソコン貸してくれてありがとう。
>
> パソコン貸してもらってありがとう。
>
> パソコン、ありがとうね。

Answer (score 1):

If they give you permission after you had already asked, just use the appropriate form of ありがとう depending on who the person is to you. There is no need to add anything extra. If they loaned you the computer then you could say thank you for lending me your computer, but you also could just give it back and say ありがとう again with a slight bow.