# Use of 抱く in "聞かせていただいてありがとうございました"

Tags: verbs, phrases

In my textbook the sentence:

> 聞かせていただいてありがとうございました

is translated as

"Thank you for telling us about all these things"

I know:

- 色々 is "various" so probably means "all these things"
- 聞かせていた means "Letting me hear"
- But 抱く, here 抱いて, means "embrace"?

I'm not really sure how to understand this. Is it simply an expression?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are missing 色々 in the sentence as it appears in your breaking down. Probably at the top of the sentence like 「色々{いろいろ} 聞かせて...」?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29752/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38802/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54455/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not parsing the sentence correctly, I'm afraid.

> 聞かせていただいてありがとうございました。

It's 聞かせて+[頂]{いただ}いて, not 聞かせていた+抱いて.

いただいて is the て form of いただく, which is the humble form of もらう.

These threads might be of help:

- [Difference between くださって and いただいて and when you should use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29752/9831)
- [How do you (not using keigo) thank someone for giving you permission to do something?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38801/9831)
- [Confused about ～させていただきたいと思います](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54344/9831)
- [Is it ok to use ～て下さりました instead of ～ていただきました?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/402/9831)